# What is the proper way to have multiple pointers to single object in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, smart-pointers

I am building 2 classes. 
Class A contains a private list of objects obj_A say list_a. 
Class B contains a list of objects obj_B say list_b. 
The objects in list_b will point to objects in list_a (and need to access the data but not modify). 
A basic version of the class looks something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//obj_A contains data
class obj_A {
  public:
    obj_A(int x) {x_ = x;};     
    void print() const {
      std::cout << "x_ = " << x_ << std::endl;
    };
  private:
    int x_;
};

//A manages list of obj_A
class A {
  public:
    void addObj(obj_A obj_a) {
      list_a_.push_back(obj_a);
    };

    obj_A* getObjPtr(int i) {
      return &list_a_[i];
    }

  private:
    std::vector<obj_A> list_a_;
};

//obj_B contains data related to obj_A
class obj_B {
  public:
    obj_B(obj_A * obj_a) : obj_a_(obj_a) {};
    void printA() const {
      obj_a_->print();
    };
  private:         
    const obj_A * obj_a_;
};

//B manages list of obj_B
class B {
  public:
    void addObj(obj_B obj_b) {
      list_b_.push_back(obj_b);
    };

    void print() const {
      for(auto b : list_b_) {
        b.printA();
      }
    };
  private:
    std::vector<obj_B> list_b_;
};

//simple example
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  //make A
  obj_A a_obj_1(1);
  obj_A a_obj_2(2);

  A a;
  a.addObj(a_obj_1);
  a.addObj(a_obj_2);

  //make B
  obj_B b_obj_1( a.getObjPtr(0) );
  obj_B b_obj_2( a.getObjPtr(0) );
  obj_B b_obj_3( a.getObjPtr(1) );

  B b;
  b.addObj(b_obj_1);
  b.addObj(b_obj_2);
  b.addObj(b_obj_3);

  //print stuff
  b.print();

  return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, creating multiple pointers (objects in list_b) to a single object (an object in list_a) is bad practice unless I use smart pointers. Is the above code bad practice? Any suggestion on how to use smart pointers instead?

Comment: Do the shared pointer denote shared ownership? Then [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is probably a good fit. Otherwise, can you guarantee that the life-time of the object will be at least the same as the last pointer to it?

Comment: "creating multiple pointers (objects in list_b) to a single object (an object in list_a) is bad practice unless I use smart pointers" where did you get that from? raw vs smart is not so much about how many pointers you have but about who owns the pointed to object

Comment: Will the pointers in list B always be destroyed before the objects in list A?

Comment: Its generally best to avoid multiple "owning" pointers to a single object, as it gets confusing over when to delete it. A `shared_ptr` somewhat helps, but Id still see that as a last resort, even in languages with garbage collection, such things can be confusing. A single owner can use `unique_ptr` if you really need a pointer at all, which makes the intent and lifecycle clear where `shared_ptr` does not.

Comment: @Galik Yes (for now), but I prefer not to rely on that constraint. The code should be safe to add or delete objects in list A or list B freely.

Comment: Bit off topic, but keep in mind that pointers to objects in a `std::vector` are dangerous.  When the vector grows its capacity they will all be invalidated.  Best to avoid storing them in a way that they could end up being used after that happens.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Thank you for your comment. Any suggestion? Alternatively, I could use `std::list`, but that would be dangerous for the same reason.

Comment: @Ralff `std::list` does not have the same issue.  Inserting or deleting elements will never invalidate pointers to objects (other than the one deleted) in the list.  The other option is to store a pointer/reference to the `std::vector` itself along with an index.  Which approach you use will really depend on the specifics of your use case.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Oh yes. You are right. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

> The objects in list_b will point to objects in list_a (and need to access the data but not modify)

Since they're read-only pointers, simply make them `const` as you already have.

As @formerlyknownas_463035818 comments, making them smart pointers is all about ownership, not how many pointers point to a single object.